Find a $G$-invariant subset using a function
Let $G$ be a countable discrete group acting on a countable set $X$.
Let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:

$f(gx)=f(x)$ for all $g \in G$
There exists a subset $A \subset X$ such that $f-1_{A} \in l^2(X)$

Find a subset $B \subset X $ satisfying:

$gB=B$  for all $g \in G$
$1_{B}-1_{A} \in l^2(X)$


Clearly you need to use $f$ to define $B$, so I thought to define $B$ as $f^{-1}(I)$ where $I$ is some interval or a real number. So $B$ is obviously $G$-invariant.
Also from triangle inequality:
$$\Vert 1_{B}-1_{A} \Vert_{2} \le \Vert 1_{B}-f \Vert_{2} + \Vert f-1_{A} \Vert_{2}$$
So given that $\Vert f-1_{A} \Vert_{2} < \infty $ it's enough to show that $\Vert 1_{B}-f \Vert_{2} < \infty $ .
I tried $B=\{x \in X :f(x)=1\}$ or $B=\{x \in X :f(x)<1/2\}$, but it didn't work...
Thanks!

Let $B=f^{-1}\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$.  It satisfies $gB=B$ for all $g$.  There are finitely many elements of $A$ outside $B$.  On the other hand there are only finitely many elements of $A^C$ in $B$.

Very helpful, thanks!
